# Asp.Net MVC 5 Restriction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to make a simple message system.In messaged table there are three significant columns which are;

> **ID of the message**
>
> **Sender's UserId**
>
> **Receiver's UserName**

I am getting the message's id from url and checking whether the logged in user is sender or receiver of that message. If not, i don't want them to see the message.

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
                var result = db.Talep.Where(e => e.ID == id && (e.UserId ==
 User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString() || e.Receiver == User.Identity.Name));
                if (result == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                Talep talep = db.Talep.Find(id);
                return View(talep);
       }
```

The fallowing code is not working, `result` never becomes null even though the statement is wrong. I tryed to use `.Any` extension but it didn't work. I hope someone can help.

Comment: use .FirstorDefault()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Where is going to always return and IEnumerable, which will never be null.

There are 2 ways to handle this:

1. change your if to this: if (!result.Any())  This will check if there are any items in the return list - if there are no items, you will return your error.
2. change your LINQ query to use FirstOrDefault()  This will return the first item that matches your request, or null if no items match.

Also a side not...  If you use FirstOrDefault(), after the if statement to check for null, you will know you have a Talep, so the last call to look up the talep by ID would be a waste.  Just return View(result)